# Apache:Two hosts pointed to same domains

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I had two websites hosted in the same server under two separate document roots. Now, the URLs for both the sites has been changed in domain level (this is done by a third party). Now, the issue appears that both the URLs are linking to the same website. Where could be the problem lies ?

This is what virtual host says:

```
NameVirtualHost 123.123.123.124:80
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.124:80>  
    ServerName www.test.com
        DocumentRoot "/path/to/document/root/"
      <Directory "/path/to/document/root/">
      php_admin_flag engine on
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride AuthConfig
Order allow,deny
allow from all
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost 123.123.123.124:80
<VirtualHost 1123.123.123.124:80>  
    ServerName www.test2.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/document/root/"
      <Directory "/path/to/document/root/">
        php_admin_flag engine on
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you post your setup code?

Comment: Are you using two different virtual hosts listening on different ports?

Comment: @JoelStüdle virtual host configuration added to post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do not have the right idea what causes the problem. but what happens if you put in this configuration for the virtual hosts:

```
# try it with the asterisks in front of :80
# are you shure 123.123.123.124 is the ip you need?
NameVirtualHost *:80

# setup for test.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/document/test/
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/path/to/document/test/">
    php_admin_flag engine on
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>

# setup for test2.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test2.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/document/test2/
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/path/to/document/test2/">
    php_admin_flag engine on
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
```

if you make changes to the vhost configuration don't forget to restart the apache server!

```
# macintosh
sudo apachectl restart

# linux
sudo service apache2 restart

# windows
# sorry i do not know :D
```